# How to mock Moto's AccountId

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest, moto

I need to change the default AccountId 123456789012 to a different value.

I tried this fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True):
def sts(monkeypatch):
    import moto.iam.models as models
    monkeypatch.setattr(models,'ACCOUNT_ID','111111111111')
    from moto import mock_sts
    with mock_sts():
        sts=boto3.client('sts',region_name='us-east-1')
        assert(sts.get_caller_identity().get('Account')=='111111111111')
        yield sts
```

But that assert fails, the AccountId is still the default...

Comment: Your example works for me if I wrap `sts.get_caller_identity().get('Account')` in `int()` because it outputs a string.

Comment: @jordanm As I mentioned, I tried that, but the actual value was different. From the sources, depending on where the resource comes from, that `moto.iam.models` is not used, the value is hardcoded (in about 50 different files)

Comment: Apparently, updating to version 1.3.14 (from 1.3.13), made it work. Thanks @jordanm

Answer (score 3):

The code included hardcoded account ids in a bunch of places. The code currently on git lets that be overwritten by setting the environment variable MOTO_ACCOUNT_ID, no need to monkey patch.

Comment: Actually, quick correction: "Don't use moto". I was using it, something broke during a version change and I almost deleted live resources. Deprecated hard internally after that. Use 'Stubber'[1] instead, way easier to set up, doesn't get outdated, and also validates (a bit) the payloads on the call
[1] https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html

Comment: "way easier to set up" -- not really. I've tried for a few hours and then gave up. My packages typically obtain clients and resources on their own. In all the examples I've seen, the model is for you to stub a resource or client, then pass them to the infrastructure being tested so that it can spit back canned responses. Unless there is something I'm missing, that is massively more complicated. If there are good docs/examples on how to use `stubber` in the context of a proper `pytest` test suite without re-engineering the package(s) being tested, I'd be very interested.

Comment: link to documentation and examples: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/multi_account.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on @FábioDias's excellent hint about the environment variable `'MOTO_ACCOUNT_ID'`, we can combine this with [moto getting started](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html#example-on-usage) as follow:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def aws_credentials(monkeypatch):
    """Mocked AWS credentials to prevent production accidents"""
    monkeypatch.setenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'testing')
    monkeypatch.setenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'testing')
    monkeypatch.setenv('AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN', 'testing')
    monkeypatch.setenv('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN', 'testing')
    monkeypatch.setenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1')
    monkeypatch.setenv('MOTO_ACCOUNT_ID', '111111111111')
    # see note 2022-06-03
    # since moto deals with ACCOUNT_ID in a "set-once" manner, we need
    # to reload moto and all of its sub-modules
    importlib.reload(sys.modules['moto'])
    to_reload = [m for m in sys.modules if m.startswith('moto.')]
    for m in to_reload:
        importlib.reload(sys.modules[m])

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def s3(aws_credentials):
    with mock_s3():
        yield boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
```

This seems to work in all cases I've tested so far.

**Note 2022-06-03**

As of now (`moto.__version__ == '3.1.12dev'`), `moto` still sets `ACCOUNT_ID` once and for all, and then copies it in various sub-modules. The only way I found to force-change the account ID everywhere is by reloading `moto` first (so that it assigns the new `ACCOUNT_ID` in `moto.core.models`) and then all sub-modules already loaded.

Comment: Actually, quick correction: "Don't use moto". I was using it, something broke during a version change and I almost deleted live resources. Deprecated _hard_ internally after that. Use 'Stubber'[1] instead, way easier to set up, doesn't get outdated, and also validates (a bit) the payloads on the call
[1] https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html